# How can I activate windows with slmgr.vbs?

Tags: windows, windows-activation

I am trying to activate a copy of Windows Server 2008 R2 through the command line. Regardless of what I try, I am unable to activate Windows except through the GUI.

Things I've tried:

```
#using slmgr
slmgr.vbs -ipk <key> -ato

#using powershell
$service = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingService"
$service.InstallProductKey($key)
$service.RefreshLicenseStatus()
```

The above methods exit without error, but the server properties page still says "need to activate". I'm rebooted as well which does not change the issue. I need to automate activation some way without use of a GUI. How can I go about doing this?

EDIT:
I can run slmgr.vbs /dli and the partial product key is correct. The status is "Notfication grace time expired"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install key command should be separate from the activate command, I.e. Run slmgr.vbs twice.

The script doesn't check or expect chained parameters like that.